# Export Mysql Table In Excel Format

Tags: php, mysql

I need to Export mysql table into Excel Format. I Have tried but still I couldn't get the correct format. can anyone please help me to fix this. I have attached my php function below.

```
<body>
<?php

function export_excel_csv()
{
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","itsup739_uaquiz","itsup739_uaquiz");
    $db = mysql_select_db("itsup739_uaquizDB",$conn);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM results";
    $rec = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($rec);

    for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++ )
    {
        $header .= mysql_field_name($rec,$i)."\\t";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rec))
    {
        $line = '';
        foreach($row as $value)
        {                                           
            if((!isset($value)) || ($value == ""))
            {
                $value = "\\t";
            }
            else
            {
                $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
                $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\\t";
            }
            $line .= $value;
        }
        $data .= trim( $line ) . "\\n";
    }

    $data = str_replace("\\r" , "" , $data);

    if ($data == "")
    {
        $data = "\\n No Record Found!\n";                       
    }

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reports.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    print "$header\\n$data";
    //echo $header;
}
export_excel_csv();
?>
```

Please Follow the link to see the output.

http://itsupportsrilanka.com/uaquiz/admin/export.php

Comment: How do you define Excel format ?

Comment: For the better solution post results in the Word format.

Comment: `<body>` tag is not required for this code. It will cause a warning.

Comment: lots of dupes in the Related Section

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export mySQL to excel or csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977113/export-mysql-to-excel-or-csv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually really really easy, to export to excel.

Just create your content as normal HTML table like this:

```
$contents = '<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bLAH BLAH</Td>
    <td>Blah Blah</td>
  </tr>
</table>';
```

Now set the headers as excel document and output your table:

```
$filename = 'my_excel_file.xls';
header( 'Content-type: application/ms-excel' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename );

echo $contents;
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: this is the simplest solution!

Answer (score 0):

1. For Excel to be able to read your table, I'd suggest you write it as a CSV file without the HTML body around the data.
2. Don't use tabs as separators. Instead use the character set in your system's locale settings (usually `,` or `;`).
3. I'm not sure this is intentional, but you escaped the backslashes for `\t` and `\n`. As such these won't represent tabs or line breaks.
4. Use `fputcsv()` to write your rows into the file (or stdout), which will by default use the CSV format understood by Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many errors.

1. `<body>` tag in the beginning will result in a warning `Cannot modify header information`. Header will not be set as the output started in the first line itself.
2. I think content type for csv is `Content-type: text/csv`