# Creating XLS file Using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am trying to create a spreadsheet (.XLS file) using Adobe ColdFusion - 8.
The code that creates a spreadsheet is:

```
<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">
<cfset date_from = "#URL.date_from#">
<cfset date_to = "#URL.date_to#">
<cfset query_id="#URL.queryID#">
<cfquery name="GetEmps" datasource="cfdocexamples">
 <!--- My SQL Queries Goes Here--->
</cfquery>

<cfcontent type="application/msexcel">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="filename=Employees.xls">
<cfoutput>
    <table cols="4">
        <cfloop query="getData">
            <tr>
                <td>#uid#</td>
                <td>#week#</td>
                <td>#book_count#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Whenever I run the page, an XLS sheet is created, but I cannot find any data. The size of the created XLS file is 0.

Please Note: The Query is correct(Since when I print the output as html, I can see the table without any error/warning).

** After reading comments: UPD**:

I had updated my code and only included important code snippet now.

**UPD 2**:

Whenever I commented the line `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="Yes">` , xls file is created with expected data. However, when I opened the generated file,  a dialogue appears:
[image]

Please note the spreadsheet generated is perfect. Only thing that is bothering me is  the above warning.
Also Note: whenever I tried to open the spreadsheet in google-docs as a preview, it says, the file could not be opened due to corrupted format.

However, I am able to open it perfectly in an MS-Excel.

Even changing content type to : `<cfcontent type="application/vnd.msexcel">` , I got  the  same warning.

Comment: I do not see where the query named 'getData' gets created. And what is `<cf_sql_select_>`?

Comment: this `<cfset date_to = "#URL.date_to#">` only needs to be `<cfset date_to = URL.date_to>` Unless you're specifically outputting data `#` are rarely needed.

Comment: @ritesh_NITW - That is because you are not really generating a *real* excel file (just html). The warning is caused by [Excel's Extension Hardening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940045/how-to-suppress-the-file-corrupt-warning-at-excel-download/940200#940200) security feature. It cannot be disabled on the server. The only way to avoid it is to ensure the content matches the extension. For example, you could use `cfspreadsheet` to generate a true excel file, or generate a CSV file instead, etc.. Just as long as the actual content matches the file extension in your `cfheader`.

Answer (score 2):

While I cannot speak exactly how to implement this, I know the developers within my organization worked around it with the [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). It seemed to do the trick for them. It does have to be completed with Java through Coldfusion. [Here](http://www.wamdevtech.com/blog/2012/12/19/apache-poi-how-to-enable-autofilter-in-coldfusion/) is an example of it.