# Export jtable to excel in javascript on IE

Tags: javascript, sql, vb.net, excel, jquery-jtable

There are many ways to export html table to excel, but what about **jtable** as it does not contain html tags like `<table>` in the page, it just calls by id like `<div id="table"></div>`

I have simple solution which is working on Chrome, but not working on IE

Button to export:

```
<a id="dlink"  onclick="tableToExcel('StudentTableContainer', 'name', 'TestExcelFile.xls')">Export to excel</a>
```

Jtable:

```
<div id="StudentTableContainer"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var tableToExcel = (function () {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function (table, name, filename) {
        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

        document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
        document.getElementById("dlink").click();

    }
})()
```

- Can we make it to use on IE?
- How can we display all the values of the
  table? (as this solution exports only displayed rows on the page)

I am using vb.net to get the sql values for jtable

Comment: Does your div id has "StudentTableContainer" or "table"?

Comment: table is generated in JavaScript file. I am just calling the id in div

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709029/export-the-html-table-to-excel-is-not-working-in-ie)?

Comment: What IE version are you using? Are there any javascript errors?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have all the rows exported you can create another jtable without paging that you load only before exporting and which is invisible to the end user. Should be something like:

```
$('#PersonTable').jtable({
    //...
    paging: false, //Set paging disabled
    actions: {
        //...
    },
    fields: {
        //...
    }
});
```

After you have the full jtable you can export it with the solution from [this forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jtable-export-to-excel). You can specify in this second jtable only the columns that you want to export in excel.