# What is correct content-type for excel files? without getting any warning

Tags: excel, vb.net

i'm trying to export my datasource from SQLserver to excel 2003 file using this code
Here :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=baseline.xls")
```

the first problem is i have to turn off protected view to open the excel file, the second problem it still give warning massege when i want to open it.

is there any idea how did i wrong ?
the warning sign :
*the file you are trying to open, baseline.xls is in a different format than specified by the file extension. verify that the file is not corrupted and is from trusted source before opening the file.*

edited : i have tried this line of code to but still have same result

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Comment: Excel 2003 creates binary files, not OpenXMLFormats XML. And [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/search?q=content+type+for+excel+2003&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) As far as the warning, see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940045/62576)

Comment: @KenWhite they talking about how to get rid the warning sign with turning off the extension, i want to get rid the warning with my code, is there any solution maybe? yeah i'm searching in google too btw

Comment: That post tells you this is a new feature of Excel itself, which you cannot get rid of in your code. Did you **read** the answers to that post, particularly the part about *Extension Hardening* (and the link to MS that is provided that explains it)?

Comment: @KenWhite ooo i see.... my bad, thanks Ken for helping me