# How to generate DB table result as Excel file in Coldfusion

Tags: javascript, excel, coldfusion-10

Is there any library or script for coldfusion that helps to generate the excel of database table data.

Comment: Have you looked at the cfspreadsheet tag https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-r-s/cfspreadsheet.html?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this will help

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfquery name="getUsers" datasource="stackoverflow">
        select * from users
    </cfquery>

    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="inline; filename=test.xlsx">
    <cfcontent type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"> 
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>firstName</th>
            <th>lastName</th>
            <th>city</th>
        </tr>
        <cfloop query="#getUsers#">
            <tr>
            <td>#firstName#</td>
            <td>#lastName#</td>
            <td>#city#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: That's not an Excel spreadsheet. It's HTML. The html trick is discouraged because it now causes a corrupt file warning in Excel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940045/how-to-suppress-the-file-corrupt-warning-at-excel-download/