# Using CFSavecontent to generate an Excel table doesn't write images to the Excel file

Tags: coldfusion

I am generating a Excel file in ColdFusion, using `cfsavecontent`. Now I want to add an image to the excel file. The code below doesn't work, resulting in a broken image.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="adc" >
   <cfoutput >
      <img src="output/homeicon.jpg">
   </cfoutput>
   <table>
      <tr>
        <!---  Total Row - 58  --->
        <!---  Row 1  --->
        <td style="width:64px;height:11px;background-color:#c0c0c0">
            <img src="output/homeicon.jpg">
        </td> <!---Column A--->
   </table>
<cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: Where the excel part?

Comment: That's not an Excel file. It's an *html* table that Excel happens to be able to open. That's relevant because images can't be *embedded* in an HTML file. See the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954446/8895292) for how to create a real Excel file, that does support embedding images. Also, while the html trick still works, it [may cause a warning due to extension hardening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940045/how-to-suppress-the-file-corrupt-warning-at-excel-download)).

Comment: @Ageax images can be embedded into HTML. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807251/can-i-embed-a-png-image-into-an-html-page . Having said that, I don't think Excel would render the image for the reasons you outlined

Comment: @JamesAMohler - True. I doubted it would work with Excel parsing html, that's why I didn't mention it.  But you're right - technically it IS possible.  Granted, I haven't actually tried this recently :-)

Answer (score 4):

Excel is very forgiving; writing an html table to a file, giving it an xlsx extension and telling Excel to open it will more or less work. But you can't do anything fancy, like embed an `img` tag and expect it work.

Coldfusion *does* have the capability to write proper xlsx files in the native format, and you *can* add an image if you do it that way. I recommend you read through https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-by-category/spreadsheet-functions.html for how to do that.